# Getting a different address from a HANDLE in C++ every time I re-compile and run the program?

Tags: c++, memory, process, handle

I'm trying to get the starting address of a process in C++ by getting the handle and printing its value. I tried getting the starting address of Spider Solitaire through Cheat Engine and it gives me "300905A4D" (currently that is). I try

```
HANDLE pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid)
```

and it gives me a different number/address every time I restart my C++ program. I keep Spider solitaire running at all times, and cheat engine keeps giving me the same starting address, but when I print

```
cout << &pHandle;
```

my c++ program gives me a different number every time. What am I doing wrong here? Also, my C++ code works fine. I can write to memory and all that, I just wonder why I'm not getting the same address Cheat Engine is giving me, and why it's a different one every time.

Comment: Possibly due to the [Address space layout randomization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) feature.

Comment: The problem is that I need the address which Cheat Engine is getting somehow as a starting address for pointer reference. See, there's a value that holds the amount of "moves" the player has made. There's a pointer behind that number, which is accessed by ANOTHER pointer (which would be the static pointer). That pointer is calculated by getting the process's base address, and if it's different every time even if it's the exact same process (i.e. never closing/restarting the program) it's supposed to remain the same. I need my program to be able to get that address so I can get the pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're printing the address of the process handle variable, and hat may be different every time your program is run -- the OS decides upon every launch of your application where to put your process and its variables in the memory.

Comment: Then how do I get the starting address of a process in C++? Apparently this doesn't quite do what I was hoping for, but I need to add some offsets to that address to get to a value that holds a certain number.

Comment: @user1007059 either find a public member of the HANDLE structure which describes the address of the process, or there's no way to do that.

Comment: @user1007059, you can't - any address you construct would be in your process address space, and not for the target process. You can access another process' memory using ReadProcessMemory/WriteProcessMemory (and that exhausts my knowledge of such things).